# Facebook started to ask read_page_mailboxes permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-messenger, facebook-page

Since today (2019-02-01) FB started to show error, when requesting [page chat history](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/conversations/):

```
(#279) Requires read_page_mailboxes permission to manage the object
```

Facebook token debugger shows these scopes:

```
email
manage_pages
pages_show_list
pages_messaging
pages_messaging_phone_number
pages_messaging_subscriptions
public_profile
```

There is no `read_page_mailboxes` permission, but it worked fine before today. There are no any warnings in App Dashboard about it.

Why is this happening. Did FB change their permission rules? Should we request for approval this permission?

**Edit:**

I tried to generate a new token, and now it has the same list of permissions except for `manage_pages`, `pages_show_list`. It looks like FB downgraded my permissions, or maybe they just expired (a previous one was generated 28 Nov).

Comment: It says right there on the page you linked to, _“A page access token with read_page_mailboxes permission can be used to view any conversation in which the page is involved.”_ - and that’s there even if you go back to the documentation for API version 2.8, so I really doubt this is something new …

Comment: @04FS but it did work several hours ago. This is very strange

Comment: It might be that one of the other permissions covers what you were doing as well, the error messages the API issues are not always a 100% spot-on. But if you “lost” manage_pages somehow, that might as well be the reason, because that is of course the basis for interacting with a page in a admin capacity to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me on the 27th of January, until 4 AM of that same day everything was working fine, after that I start getting errors from my app saying that I don't have the necessary permissions.

```
 {
  "error": {
    "message": "(#279) Requires read_page_mailboxes permission to manage the object",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    ...
  }
}
```

Later that night, while I was trying to find a workaround to the App Review process (which is needed to add that permission), messing with the App Settings, I found the option "Business Use" and set it o "Support my own business".

[image: App/Settings/Basic]

Around the same time I made those changes my requests started working again (upon inspection I found that my Page Access Token had, once again, all the needed permissions (including "read_page_mailboxes"). I'm not 100% sure that that specific setting was the reason but the timing was really odd). After a few days, on the 4th of February, the problem came back and hasn't stopped until the time of this post.

Comment: After further verification, I noticed that this problem only occurred for some periods during the day (not every single day). Example, on the 6th I was able to retrieve messages until 5 PM, on the 7th I didn't get any error whatsoever. I'm still trying to find a way to understand this behaviour, it would be awesome to have some kind of log to check for changes on the App, Page, tokens etc.